# Django, Google App Engine, datastore, user login

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-users

I am trying to setup a web app in django and deploy on GAE, I already had a setup for GAE,social-auth ( django-social-auth), now I am trying to add userena, to handle the user login; however, it cannot deploy on the GAE, since the userena wouldn't allow models.OneToOneField to create user model in the datastore. I am looking for a django-login package which wouldn't make this problem for me, or if you have any suggestion to fix this issue for me. I am using the http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html#required-settings and this is my error.

`File "/git/ePapyri/epapyri-django/djangoappengine/db/base.py", line 160, in _value_for_db raise DatabaseError("Only strings and positive integers " django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Only strings and positive integers may be used as keys on GAE.`

Comment: I change datastore to google Cloud SQL service. I was following this tutorial http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-on-appengine-using-google-cloud-sql and everything works after. The main problem is django-nonrel does not support OneToOneField. So I ended up to change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I change datastore to google Cloud SQL service. I was following this tutorial howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/… and everything works after. The main problem is django-nonrel does not support OneToOneField. So I ended up to change the setting.